# Creating an @mention system with a suggestion list in a textarea using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, list, textarea, mention

I would like to create an @mention system in a textarea where any word that begins with @ is highlighted in blue color. In addition, when the user starts typing @, a suggestion list should appear next to the cursor that provides a list of selectable options. This can be achieved using JavaScript.

"@mention" text is not appearing in blue when typed, and the list that opens when "@" is typed does not appear next to the cursor.

Comment: You won't be able to change the colour of individual words in a textarea. You can probably define a `div` (for example) as `contenteditable` and then wrap certain words in a span, using CSS to colour those instead.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.